# Intra-package reference of modules in sub-packages using dotted syntax

Tags: python, module, package

I have the following package structure:

```
.
└── package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── sub_package_1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── main_module.py
    ├── sub_package_2
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── some_module.py
    └── sub_package_3
        ├── __init__.py
        └── some_module.py
```

In `package/sub_package_1/main_module.py` I want to use both `package/sub_package_2/some_module.py` and `package/sub_package_3/some_module.py`. For this I want to use [intra-package reference](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). I know that I can use `from ..sub_package_1 import some-module` but because of the similar name I want to use dotted syntax such as `sub_package_1.some_module`.

Using `from .. import sub_package_2` I obviously cannot access `sub_package_2.some_module` because `sub_package_2` is a package. However I found out that using

```
from .. import sub_package_2
from ..sub_package_2 import some_module
```

I can access `sub_package_2.some_module`. Apparently the 2nd import adds `some_module` to `sub_package_2` (checking `dir(sub_package_2)`).

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a way to use a single import instead of the two above?
2. Why does (in general) `import package` followed by `from package import module` add `module` to `package`? What is Python actually doing here?

Answer (score 2):

1.

In the file `__init__.py` of sub_package_2 you write

```
from . import some_module
```

And in `main_module.py` you can must write

```
from .. import sub_package_2
```

And the code `sub_package_2.some_module` should work now

2.

"How import in python work" you can read more here [Importing Python Modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)

`from .. import sub_package_2` creates a reference to `sub_package_2` in the current namespace. Package `sub_package_2` is like a module now and is defined in the file `__init__.py`. If you wrote nothing in `__init__.py`, sub_package_2 won't know `some_modue`

`from ..sub_package_2 import some_module` create a reference to the module `some_module` of the package `sub_package_2` with the name **some_module**. It's something like `some_module = sub_package_2.some_module`. You see: there are a reference to `some_module` in `sub_package_2` too. And now `sub_package_2` knows the module `some_module`

Important: You can use `sub_package_2.some_module` but only `some_module` will work too. They are identical after your 2 imports.

And if you write in the `__init__.py`:

```
from . import some_module
```

`some_module` belongs to `sub_package_2` automatically

For similar module names you can use `as`

```
from ..sub_package_1 import some_module as some_module_1
from ..sub_package_2 import some_module as some_module_2
from ..sub_package_3 import some_module as some_module_3
```

Comment: Thanks! And is there any (technical) difference in writing `import some_module` instead of `from . import some_module` in `__init__.py`? Python anyway tries first to import from the current package, doesn't it?

Comment: They are in your case the same but technically not the same. `from . import xxx` can only import modules/packages in your package. If the module `xxx` doesn't exist in your package -> always Error. `import xxx` can import  module `xxx` from python libs, if the module `xxx` doesn't exist in your package.